# Questions on how the workflow works for making changes after a PR has been reviewed, and git rebasing

Tags: git, github, rebase, pull-request

I've never really used git rebase before, on other projects we've always just merged the code after a PR has been made.

On this new project I'm on, the team uses git rebase.  I think I have a very basic understanding of it.  After you're done and ready to make a PR, pull the latest from the base branch, switch back to your branch then git rebase that branch onto yours.

I've done that, pushed my code up for a PR review and there are a couple files that I need to make changes on.

My question is...
My local branch has already been rebased, to make corrections on the files that need changes, would I just go back to my local branch thats been rebased, make the corrections, commit my changes, then rebase again and push my branch up?

Comment: No need to rebase again, unless the base branch has had additional changes since you rebased the first time.

Comment: Ooooohhhhh wait wait wait!!! Careful with the wording here: `After you're done and ready to make a PR, pull the latest from the base branch, switch back to your branch then git rebase that branch onto yours`. Then git rebase that branch (your branch? that's the last branch you checked out if I understand correctly when you say **switch back to your branch**, I read it as your feature branch) onto yours? So that means rebasing a branch onto itself? I guess that's not what you mean. Can you check the wording?

Comment: Thanks for checking, I'll give you an example:

Im on my branch "mybranch1"
I make some changes, git add . , git commit -m "some message"

After that, I switch to the master branch, git pull origin master

Switch back to mybranch1, git rebase master

Hopefully that clarifies